# How to count the number of class of a page to display it in a menu?

Tags: javascript, php, css, drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8.8.4 site with Bootstrap 3.4.1 theme

I have created a store view page to display the tasks to be performed by merchants.

On this page, each task corresponds to a view block :

- The orange blocks have the class "task-list-warning".
- The red blocks have the class "task-list-danger".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVChc.png)

There is a menu link to display this page and I added 2 badges :

- With the class "task-badge-warning".
- With the class "task-badge-danger".

I want to display the number of tasks on the page, in the menu link badges :

- The number of class "task-list-warning" in the "task-badge-warning".
- The number of class "task-list-danger" in the "task-badge-danger".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QeaB.png)

The store menu is a TWIG file containing the following code :

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="menu-page-boutique" id="menu-page-boutique" class="contextual-region">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav m-0">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Gérer votre {{ store_entity.type.entity.label }}</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="task">
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/tasks" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/tasks"><i class="fas fa-tasks fa-lg"></i> <b>Liste des tâches</b> <span class="badge badge-warning task-badge-warning">0</span> <span class="badge badge-danger task-badge-danger">0</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/point-of-sale" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/point-of-sale"><i class="fas fa-cash-register fa-lg"></i> Point de vente</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/migrate" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/migrate"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt  fa-lg"></i> Migrer</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}"><i class="fas fa-glasses  fa-lg"></i> Voir</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/edit" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/edit"><i class="fas fa-feather-alt fa-lg"></i> Modifier</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/delete" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i> Supprimer</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/translations" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/translations"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Traductions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/members" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/members"><i class="fas fa-sitemap fa-lg"></i> L'équipe</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/relationship" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/relationship"><i class="fas fa-link  fa-lg"></i> Relations</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/products" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/products"><i class="fas fa-gift  fa-lg"></i> Produits</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/promotions" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/promotions"><i class="fas fa-percentage fa-lg"></i> Promotions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/payment-gateways" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/payment-gateways"><i class="fas fa-credit-card fa-lg"></i> Modes de paiement</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/shipping-methods" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/shipping-methods"><i class="fas fa-truck fa-lg"></i> Modes de livraison</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/orders" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/orders"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i> Commandes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/inventory" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/inventory"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-lg"></i> Inventaire</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/reports" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/reports"><i class="fas fa-calculator fa-lg"></i> Rapports de vente</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/like" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/like"><i class="fas fa-heartbeat fa-lg"></i> Mentions j'aime</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/seo" data-drupal-link-system-path="/store/{{ store_entity.id }}/seo"><i class="fas fa-flag-checkered fa-lg"></i> Référencement</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I do this ?

**THE PROBLEM**

I started a module for Drupal 8 :

https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3076032/tree/master

It only works if I'm on the task page. But if I go to another page, the counter in the menu does not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiAUE.png)

How to display the task counter on all pages where the menu is present ?

The menu is displayed on all pages with the url :

```
https://www.example.com/fr/store/ID_STORE
https://www.example.com/en/store/ID_STORE
https://www.example.com/fr/store/ID_STORE/*
https://www.example.com/en/store/ID_STORE/*
```